# RippleDrawable not working as drawable for ViewGroup

Tags: android, xml

I was trying to apply RippleEffect by RippleDrawable method of android where I defined the ripple in the drawable first as this:-
[image: My file name is ugb.xml]

The file name is ugb.xml

Then I tried to apply it as a layout for my Navigation Drawer(Recycler View) in the layout(for the Recycler View Item) I created for my individual rows as a background as following:
[image: My row folder of Recycler View]

It just shows an exclamation mark and when I hover on it ,it shows no error message. Also when I click it, it just opens my ripple drawable file.

Is there any better way to do it?

Thank you in advance..!!

Comment: And please comment on the question..!! I'm still new on the community and don't understand still what questions we can ask or not. If you feel this question is inappropriate then before flagging please just comment once as to how the question is inappropriate coz I really wanna be a part of this community. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ignore the icon, is the code working or not?

Comment: @TimCastelijns  Yes..!! everything is working except for the ripple effect..!! The alternate version of ugb.xml which is for supporting API devices before 21 is also working!! Only the v21/ugb.xml with the ripple effect is not working..!!

Comment: Name the folder `drawable-v21`

Comment: @TimCastelijns its in the drawable-v21 folder only..!

Comment: Have you tried an other color?

Comment: @oberflansch yes just tried..!!! Worked just fine..!! The exclamation mark was still present but the code worked...!! Thanks  a lot..!

Comment: By the way I tried again by first making a color attribute of the ?android:attr/colorPrimaryHighlight and then applied it..!! It worked this way also..! Thank you for helping again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For other users who struggle with this

**Solution:**

Change the color of the ripple drawable, the white ripple color might not visible.